# Алгоритм RSA

Tags: алгоритм, rsa

Следующий пример наглядно демонстрирует алгоритм шифрования RSA:

Зашифруем и расшифруем сообщение "САВ" по алгоритму RSA. Для простоты возьмем небольшие числа - это сократит наши расчеты.

```
* Выберем p=3 and q=11.
* Определим n= 3*11=33.
* Hайдем (p-1)*(q-1)=20. Следовательно, d будет равно, например, 3: (d=3).
* Выберем число е по следующей формуле: (e*3) mod 20=1. Значит е будет равно, например, 7: (e=7).
* Представим шифруемое сообщение как последовательность чисел в диапозоне от 0 до 32 (незабывайте, что кончается на n-1). Буква А =1, В=2, С=3.
```

Теперь зашифруем сообщение, используя открытый ключ {7,33}

```
C1 = (3^7) mod 33 = 2187 mod 33 = 9;
C2 = (1^7) mod 33 = 1 mod 33 = 1;
C3 = (2^7) mod 33 = 128 mod 33 = 29;
```

Теперь расшифруем данные, используя закрытый ключ {3,33}.

```
M1=(9^3) mod 33 =729 mod 33 = 3(С);
M2=(1^3) mod 33 =1 mod 33 = 1(А);
M3=(29^3) mod 33 = 24389 mod 33 = 2(В);
```

Вот меня интересует этот момент:

> Выберем число е по следующей формуле:
> (e*3) mod 20=1.
> Определим такое число е, для которого является истинным следующее соотношение (e*d) mod ((p-1)*(q-1))=1.

Как подбирается это число? Методом тыка? Или, все же, можно как-то привести в виду `е=`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mod` - сравнение по модулю в математике и остаток от деления в программировании.

На сколько я понял, `e` должно быть одним из чисел, которое больше 1 и меньше `(p-1)*(q-1)` (не включительно). Дальше оно должно быть с функцией  `(p-1)*(q-1)` [взаимно-простым](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0). Т.е. выбирается **НЕ** от балды.

Comment: Попробую сформулировать вопрос по-простому: `(e*3) mod 20=1`.
Как ты будешь искать `е`?

Comment: Ну, до алгоритма нахождения взаимно-простых чисел к некоторому вы можете сами додуматься (просто погуглить). Тут `e` - открытый ключ. Так что можно выбрать в качестве `e` - случайное число, если взаимно-простых чисел к `(p-1)*(q-1)` больше одного.

Comment: e = (20*x + 1)/3; x - любое целое

Comment: И не забывайте, что `(p-1)*(q-1)`, при `p != q`; `p,q` - prime; - это показатель количества простых чисел меньше `n (pq = n)`